# fieldset's top border not showing up

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this below code in my html/css. I am looking for a design like this:
[image]

I used this http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Gsj27/3/ fiddle to work with to partition the fieldsets.
**But I am unable to show the top border of the fieldset.**
[image]

```
<section style="width: 95%;">
   <div id="one">
      <fieldset style="border: solid; border-width: thin; height: 200px; border-color: #a8a8a8;">
         <legend id="Legend10" runat="server" visible="true" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #1f497d;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Project Summary &nbsp;&nbsp;</legend>
         <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
         <asp:Table ID="table10" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
            <asp:TableRow>
               <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                  Project ID: 
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
               </asp:TableCell>
               <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                  Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
               </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow>
               <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                  Project ID: 
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
               </asp:TableCell>
               <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                  Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
               </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
         </asp:Table>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
   <div id="two">
      <fieldset style="border: solid; border-width: thin; height: 200px; border-color: #a8a8a8;">
         <legend id="Legend5" runat="server" visible="true" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #1f497d;"></legend>
         <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
            <asp:Table ID="table11" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
               <asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                     Project ID: 
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </asp:TableCell>
                  <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </asp:TableCell>
               </asp:TableRow>
               <asp:TableRow>
                  <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                     Project ID: 
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </asp:TableCell>
                  <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                     <asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </asp:TableCell>
               </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.labels {
    font-size:9pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Calibri;
}

section {
    width: 95%;
    height: 200px; 
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 47%;
    height: 200px; 
    float: left;
}
div#two { 
    height: 200px; 
}
fieldset legend {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The legend needed width:auto. This solved the issue.

```
 <legend id="Legend5" runat="server" visible="true" style="width:auto; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #1f497d;">
```

Comment: Really glad that helped cuz I was going mad over it as well.

Answer (score 4):

Add width: auto to stylesheet. This will solve it.

```
width:auto;
```

Comment: to which css elem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

css

```
 <style>
.verticalLine {
  border-left: thick solid #ff0000;
            height: 143px;
        }
    .labels {
    font-size:9pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Calibri;
}

section {
    width: 95%;
    height: 200px; 
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#one {
    width: 45%;
    height: 200px; 

}
div#two  
{
     width: 45%;
    height: 200px; 
    float: right;
}
    </style>
```

HTML

```
<section style="width: 95%;">
                           <div id="one">
                            <fieldset style="border: solid; border-width: thin; height: 200px; border-color: #a8a8a8;">
                                <legend id="Legend10" runat="server" visible="true" style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #1f497d;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Project Summary &nbsp;&nbsp;</legend>
                                <table border="1">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                 <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <asp:Table ID="table11" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
                                        <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                                                   Project ID: 
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                                                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                                                   Project ID: 
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                                                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                    </asp:Table>
                                </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                 <div class="verticalLine">

</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div  style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">
                                    <asp:Table ID="table10" runat="server" CssClass="labels">
                                         <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                                                   Project ID: 
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                                                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                        <asp:TableRow>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 10%;">
                                                   Project ID: 
                                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="25px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                            <asp:TableCell Style="width: 40%;">
                                                     Project Name:<sup style="color:red; font-size:10pt;">*q</sup> 
                                                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="90px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </asp:TableCell>
                                        </asp:TableRow>
                                    </asp:Table>
                                </div>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>





                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                        </div>

                    </section>
```

Comment: another div is hiding the div one border, if anything above section please remove that and check...there is no problem in field set

Comment: I have one <fieldset> and  <br />   followed by the above code. I tried removing it but issue is still there.

Comment: When I change display: block; to display: inline;  in fieldset css I can see the border but legend is coming in side the fieldset.

Comment: in jsfiddle asp tags are not supported I guess, as you cannot see textboxes. It behaves a little different with asp tags.

Comment: is your problem in only fieldset top border or textbox border too?

Comment: just fieldset., all i was saying is you cannot replicate this issue in jsfiddle. you need visual studio.

Comment: nevermind. I got the issue. I wasn't using the width:auto in fieldset's legend style. It's now working.